# Getting error while using a custom directive in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete, jsfiddle, directive

I am using an "auto-complete" directive from [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zbjzznkc/) and getting the error as `iElement.autocomplete is not a function`.
Please help me out to solve this error.

directive.js

```
starter.directive('autoComplete', function($timeout) {
    return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            iElement.autocomplete({
                source: function(request, response) {
                    var res = new Array()
                    for (var i=0; i<scope[iAttrs.uiItems].length; i++) {
                        if (scope[iAttrs.uiItems][i].indexOf(request.term) == 0) {
                               res.push(scope[iAttrs.uiItems][i]);
                        }
                    }
                    response(res);
                },
                select: function() {
                    $timeout(function() {
                      iElement.trigger('input');
                    }, 0);
                }
            });
    };
});
```

.html file

```
<input type="text" auto-complete="true" ui-items="names" ng-model="selected" class="tagdiv" style="color:#fff" placeholder="Tag your category">
```

.js file

```
$scope.names = ["john", "bill", "charlie", "robert", "alban", "oscar", "marie", "celine", "brad", "drew", "rebecca", "michel", "francis", "jean", "paul", "pierre", "nicolas", "alfred", "gerard", "louis", "albert", "edouard", "benoit", "guillaume", "nicolas", "joseph"];
```

Comment: please add your code

Comment: It means that you didn't load jQueryUI. Or make sure you load jQuery before Agnular.

Comment: and I think your directive's implementation is wrong. You should return an object with your defined function as the `link` property

Comment: when I load jQueryUI, it again gives me an error as `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in your jsfiddle you didn't include the jquery-ui javascript, which causes the error you mentioned.

Also, your directive's implementation is wrong. The directive should return an object with the configuration for the directive, and not a function:

```
starter.directive('autoComplete', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: "AE",
        scope: {
            uiItems: "="
        },
        link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            iElement.autocomplete({
                // not sure why you had a whole function here, this should do the trick:
                source: scope.uiItems,
                select: function() {
                    $timeout(function() {
                        iElement.trigger('input');
                    }, 0);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zbjzznkc/10/)